# Get bytecode (.class files) from user-selected source items

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want my plugin (an automated termination analysis tool) to run on code the user selects inside Eclipse. Naturally, the user selects source code (a `.java` file, a method in the outline, ...). However, my program needs the compiled `.class` file(s) as input.

How can I get the `.class` files for selected source items? Related to this, how can I get a bytecode descriptor to the selected source method? In case of generics and varargs transforming a (Eclipse) source descriptor to the corresponding bytecode descriptor seems nontrivial to me.

I do not want to run `javac` on my own and I do not want to guess how the `.class` file is named (this is nasty for inner classes) and then try to find it on the disk (if it exists? maybe I can force Eclipse to compile?).

Comment: It seems the FindBugs plugin generates a list of patterns (`Foo.java` -> `Foo.class`, `Foo$1.class`, ...) and somehow finds these files. This is what I do not want to do. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bytecode Outline plugin uses the following solution (see `JdtUtils.getByteCodePath`):

1. Based on the source element, find the output location, e.g. `/home/user/workspace/project/build/`)
2. Use the package information to find the right directory inside `build/`, e.g. `/home/user/workspace/project/build/some/package/`
3. Find the "outermost" class definition (important for inner classes), use this name as the  file name of the `.class` file, e.g. `/home/user/workspace/project/build/some/package/Foo.class`
4. in case of an inner class, do weird magic (`JdtUtils.getClassName`) and modify the name of the resulting class file accordingly (maybe resulting in `Foo$1.class`)

So the problem of this question is solved, where the translation of inner classes to the corresponding file names could be improved. According to the author, though, the current approach (using "magic") works for "95% of the cases" and he does not know about any related bugs in the past few years.